# Convert a tensor of shape (?,32,24,24) into a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have a tensor with a batch of 32 grayscale images, each of size 24x24.

The tensor is produced after a Conv2D layer in a CNN built using Keras with tensorflow backend. The data is provided to the model as a numpy array.

Now, I wish to covert the output tensor into a numpy array, and again back into a tensor.

I have referred to [this page](https://www.aiworkbox.com/lessons/numpy-array-to-tensorflow-tensor-and-back) and wrote this simple piece of code that doesn't seem to work

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
ip = np.array(x.eval())
```

here, x is my tensor and ip is the intended numpy array. This throws as InvalidArgumentError(). Is there any way I can get rid of the unkown (?) dimension?

Here's the stack trace:

```
 Message=InvalidArgumentError()
  Source=c:\users\rangan\source\repos\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn\fuzzyconv2d.py
  StackTrace:
  File "c:\users\rangan\source\repos\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn\fuzzyconv2d.py", line 31, in call
    ip = np.array(x.eval())
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 507, in __call__
    inputs=to_list(inputs))
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 185, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "c:\users\rangan\source\repos\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn.py", line 39, in baseline_model
    model.add(F_Conv2D(5))
  File "c:\users\rangan\source\repos\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn\fuzzycnn.py", line 49, in <module>
    model = baseline_model()
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], including code that *we* can run which demonstrates the problem, the current output, and the expected output.

Comment: Also, if there is an error, please copy/paste the *entire* error trace, not just the error type.

Answer (score 1):

The output tensor value is, by definition, computed for a certain input batch.  You need to pass a value for the input to the eval function:

```
ip = x.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={input: X_batch})
```

As long as x is the tensor of interest and 'input' the input place holder, this is the simplest way to get the value of a tensor.